# Is it possible to ignore out in %time and %timeit magic function in ipython console?

Tags: python, ipython

In `ipython` console, we can use the magic function `%time` and `%timeit` to easily measure the performance of some computing. e.g.:

```
%time 2 ** 123
%time(math.factorial(123))
```

or in the function call:

```
time(2 ** 123)
time(math.factorial(123))


%time 2**1234
CPU times: user 0 ns, sys: 0 ns, total: 0 ns
Wall time: 9.06 µs
Out[41]: 295811224608098629060044695716103590786339687135372992239556207050657350796238924261053837248378050186443647759070955993120820899330381760937027212482840944941362110665443775183495726811929203861182015218323892077355983393191208928867652655993602487903113708549402668624521100611794270340232766099317098048887493809023127398253860618772619035009883272941129544640111837184L
```

Is it possible to ignore the out put of the computing, just the wall time information?

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the output of `%time` to a dummy variable:

```
_ = %time 2**1234
```

outputs:

```
CPU times: user 3 µs, sys: 0 ns, total: 3 µs
Wall time: 8.11 µs
```